# How to SELECT the result of RETURNING

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert-into, sql-returning

How to put the result of a [`RETURNING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/dml-returning.html) clause into a `SELECT` in PostgreSQL? I.e., I would like the `SELECT` statement to return whatever `RETURNING` returns.

I have tried the following two syntaxes, none of them seem to work:

`(1) SELECT (INSERT INTO ... RETURNING *)`

`(2) SELECT * FROM (INSERT INTO ... RETURNING *) ...`

You might ask, why I'm trying to do this, in spite of `RETURNING` already giving me the desired result?
It's because I have a structure using two `WITH` clauses, and the insertion would be in the second one, but I also need the results of the first one. (See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54791076/two-with-clauses-do-an-insert-in-the-second-but-keep-the-result-of-the-first).)

Remark: unfortunately, I cannot provide the concrete SQL query (because it is in a closed source product), but I think the question is generic enough to be answerable without this concrete query.

**EDIT** Added example:

Suppose we have this table:

`CREATE TABLE test(id INT, name VARCHAR)`

This works:

`INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'Joe') RETURNING *`

What I'm trying to do, but does not work:

`SELECT INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'Joe') RETURNING *`

`SELECT * FROM INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'Joe') RETURNING *`

Comment: Have you tried `RETURNING * INTO record` and then selecting the record variable? Also, would it be possible to have another with clause after the `INSERT` rather than trying to `SELECT` from the subquery? It would be helpful to just have the structure of the query. You don't need to give us all the details but you mention two with clauses...maybe just give a basic example.

Comment: Ok, I'll put together an example.

Answer (score 1):

`insert ... returning *` will already return a result set, there is no need to add a SELECT statement to it.

But if you insist, you could do

```
with i as (
   INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'Joe') 
   RETURNING *
)
select *
from i;
```

But that returns exactly the same thing as:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'Joe') 
RETURNING *
```