# Two WITH clauses, do an INSERT in the second, but keep the result of the first

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider the following query with two [`WITH` clauses](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html)

```
WITH result1 AS (
     SELECT ...
),
result2 AS (
     INSERT INTO...
)
SELECT <logic dependent on result1>
```

In case that matters, I don't need `result2`, however the order of the clauses is important, so I cannot exchange them (i.e. calculate first `result2` and then `result1`).

Question: how can I pass on `result1` through the second clause, so that it is available in the `SELECT`?

I already tried using the [`RETURNING` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/dml-returning.html), but that [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790915/how-to-select-the-result-of-returning)...

**EDIT** Example:

Consider the following table/content:

`CREATE TABLE test(id INT, name VARCHAR)`

`INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'Joe')`

Then the following query gives me an error:

```
WITH result1 AS (
     SELECT name FROM test WHERE id = 1
), result2 AS (
     INSERT INTO test VALUES(2, 'Jack') RETURNING *
) SELECT result1.id == 5 FROM result1
```

Result:

```
ERROR: column result1.id does not exist
LINE 8: ) SELECT result1.id == 5 FROM result1
                 ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 216
```

I tried also `... FROM result2` (obviously wrong, because what I need is in `result1`) and `... FROM result1, result2` (same issue, and it suggests me to use `result2.id` instead).

Comment: Yes you can! Please post real code, instead of the `...`

Comment: I can't post the real code, but I'll make up a minimal example.

Comment: Why do you need to "pass it through `result2`"?  You can just access `result1` in any query that needs the info.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I thought I was getting an error, when not "passing through", that's why I assumed I should. But maybe I missed something, let me check again.

Comment: I edited my answer after attempting an SQLFiddle. That should do the trick for you.

Comment: `SELECT result1.id == 5 FROM result1` is nonsense even without the CTE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH result1 AS (
    SELECT ... 
), result2 AS (
    INSERT INTO ... 
), final AS (
    SELECT result1.<some_column>
         , result2.<some_other_column>
    FROM result1, result2
)
SELECT * FROM final;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works indeed. However, I see now that my example is wrong (I'm indeed querying a field that does not exist), so probably the combination is not even needed, and your previous answer was also correct :)

Answer (score 2):

Fix your `result1` CTE if you want to return `id`:

```
WITH result1 AS (
      SELECT id, name
      FROM test
      WHERE id = 1
     )
```

Then you can reference `result1.id` in the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: Yep, indeed, I just noticed I had made this mistake. Thanks for pointing it out :)